# Understanding GoapPlanner script

Tags: c#

I am still pretty new to programming and came across this script and I have a question about some of the logic. My question has to do with the `buildGraph()`

```
 private bool buildGraph(Node parent, List<Node> leaves, HashSet<GoapAction> usableActions, HashSet<KeyValuePair<string, object>> goal)
{

    bool foundOne = false;

    // go through each action available at this node and see if we can use it here
    foreach (GoapAction action in usableActions)
    {

        // if the parent state has the conditions for this action's preconditions, we can use it here
        if (inState(action.Preconditions, parent.state))
        {

            // apply the action's effects to the parent state
            HashSet<KeyValuePair<string, object>> currentState = populateState(parent.state, action.Effects);
            //Debug.Log(GoapAgent.prettyPrint(currentState));

            Node node = new Node(parent, parent.runningCost + action.cost, currentState, action);

            if (inState(goal, currentState))
            {
                // we found a solution! 
                leaves.Add(node);
                foundOne = true;
            }
            else
            {
                // not at a solution yet.
                HashSet<GoapAction> subset = actionSubset(usableActions, action);
                bool found = buildGraph(node, leaves, subset, goal);
                if (found)
                    foundOne = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return foundOne;
}
```

I am still new to programming and this answer will really help me out.

To ask my question I need to talk through the logic. The code in question is designed to find multiple solutions and then calculates which is the most efficient.

[image]

Each time the state conditions meet the preconditions

> if ( inState(action.Preconditions, parent.state) )

the code will add in the effect.

> HashSet > currentState = populateState
>   (parent.state, action.Effects);

We then create a node and save the action, cost, and state

> Node node = new Node(parent, parent.runningCost+action.cost,
>   currentState, action);

If the parent state matches our goal

> if (inState(goal, currentState))

we add our node to the leaves list as a solution.

> leaves.Add(node);

In the leaves list, we find the cheapest node and that will be the best path. If there are multiple solutions the list will contain multiple nodes.

**Now my Question**

I don’t understand how the script is able to continue looking for other solutions and paths once one solution has been found. Once it comes across the first solution, the goal effect is added in to the current state. The foreach loop will continue to pull actions from the usableActions HashSet, however, wouldn’t every action tested afterwards show up as being solutions, since the first solution has changed the state and added the goal effect in? I would think the state would need to be changed back to avoid this otherwise it wont make it to the recursive step. The script works fine, so there is clearly something  I am not quite understanding.

This code was taken from the GoapPlanner, here is the complete code for the planner.

```
 public class GoapPlanner
{

    /**
     * Plan what sequence of actions can fulfill the goal.
     * Returns null if a plan could not be found, or a list of the actions
     * that must be performed, in order, to fulfill the goal.
     */
    public Queue<GoapAction> plan(GameObject agent,
                                  HashSet<GoapAction> availableActions,
                                  HashSet<KeyValuePair<string, object>> worldState,
                                  HashSet<KeyValuePair<string, object>> goal)
    {
        // reset the actions 
        foreach (GoapAction a in availableActions)
        {
            a.doReset();
        }

        // check which actions can run using their checkProceduralPrecondition
        HashSet<GoapAction> usableActions = new HashSet<GoapAction>();
        foreach (GoapAction a in availableActions)
        {
            if (a.checkProceduralPrecondition(agent))
                usableActions.Add(a);
        }


        // build up the tree and record the leaf nodes that provide a solution to the goal. 
        List<Node> leaves = new List<Node>();

        // build graph
        Node start = new Node(null, 0, worldState, null); 
        bool success = buildGraph(start, leaves, usableActions, goal);

        if (!success)
        {
            // oh no, we didn't get a plan
            Debug.Log("NO PLAN");
            return null;
        }


        // gets the cheapest leaf. 
        Node cheapest = null;

        foreach (Node leaf in leaves)
        {

            if (cheapest == null)
                cheapest = leaf;
            else
            {

                if (leaf.runningCost < cheapest.runningCost)
                {
                    cheapest = leaf;
                }
            }

        }

        List<GoapAction> result = new List<GoapAction>();

        Node n = cheapest;
        while (n != null)
        {
            if (n.action != null)
            {

                result.Insert(0, n.action); // insert the action in the front.
            }
            n = n.parent;
        }

        // we now have actions in correct order in results list and we want to add it to the queue.
        Queue<GoapAction> queue = new Queue<GoapAction>();
        foreach (GoapAction a in result)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(a);

        }

        // hooray we have a plan!
        return queue;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if at least one solution was found.
     * The possible paths are stored in the leaves list. Each leaf has a
     * 'runningCost' value where the lowest cost will be the best action
     * sequence.
     */
    private bool buildGraph(Node parent, List<Node> leaves, HashSet<GoapAction> usableActions, HashSet<KeyValuePair<string, object>> goal)
    {

        bool foundOne = false;

        // go through each action available at this node and see if we can use it here
        foreach (GoapAction action in usableActions)
        {

            // if the parent state has the conditions for this action's preconditions, we can use it here
            if (inState(action.Preconditions, parent.state))
            {

                // apply the action's effects to the parent state
                HashSet<KeyValuePair<string, object>> currentState = populateState(parent.state, action.Effects);
                //Debug.Log(GoapAgent.prettyPrint(currentState));

                Node node = new Node(parent, parent.runningCost + action.cost, currentState, action);

                if (inState(goal, currentState))
                {
                    // we found a solution! 
                    leaves.Add(node);
                    foundOne = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    // not at a solution yet.
                    HashSet<GoapAction> subset = actionSubset(usableActions, action);
                    bool found = buildGraph(node, leaves, subset, goal);
                    if (found)
                        foundOne = true;
                }
            }
        }

        return foundOne;
    }

    /**
     * Create a subset of the actions excluding the removeMe one. 
     */
    private HashSet<GoapAction> actionSubset(HashSet<GoapAction> actions, GoapAction removeMe)
    {
        HashSet<GoapAction> subset = new HashSet<GoapAction>();
        foreach (GoapAction a in actions)
        {
            if (!a.Equals(removeMe))
                subset.Add(a);
        }
        return subset;
    }

    /**
     * Check that all items in 'test' are in 'state'. If just one does not match or is not there
     * then this returns false.
     */
    private bool inState(HashSet<KeyValuePair<string, object>> test, HashSet<KeyValuePair<string, object>> state)
    {
        bool allMatch = true;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> t in test)
        {
            bool match = false;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> s in state)
            {
                if (s.Equals(t))
                {
                    match = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!match)
                allMatch = false;
        }
        return allMatch;
    }

    /**
     * Apply the stateChange to the currentState
     */
    private HashSet<KeyValuePair<string, object>> populateState(HashSet<KeyValuePair<string, object>> currentState, HashSet<KeyValuePair<string, object>> stateChange)
    {
        HashSet<KeyValuePair<string, object>> state = new HashSet<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
        // copy the KVPs over as new objects
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> s in currentState)
        {
            state.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(s.Key, s.Value));
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> change in stateChange)
        {
            // if the key exists in the current state, update the Value
            bool exists = false;

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> s in state)
            {
                if (s.Equals(change))
                {
                    exists = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (exists)
            {
                state.RemoveWhere((KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp) => { return kvp.Key.Equals(change.Key); });
                KeyValuePair<string, object> updated = new KeyValuePair<string, object>(change.Key, change.Value);
                state.Add(updated);
            }
            // if it does not exist in the current state, add it
            else
            {
                state.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(change.Key, change.Value));
            }
        }
        return state;
    }

    /**
     * Used for building up the graph and holding the running costs of actions.
     */
    private class Node
    {
        public Node parent;
        public float runningCost;
        public HashSet<KeyValuePair<string, object>> state;
        public GoapAction action;

        public Node(Node parent, float runningCost, HashSet<KeyValuePair<string, object>> state, GoapAction action) //state should be world state
        {
            this.parent = parent;
            this.runningCost = runningCost;
            this.state = state;
            this.action = action;
        }
    }
}
```